# Do I have binomial data, and how do I treat it?

Tags: chi-squared-test, binomial-distribution, standard-error

I have field observations that are essentially presence/absence, but here are the details: randomly placed quadrats are divided into 10 squares. The field data recorded are the number of squares which have a subject present. There are 30 quadrats at a reference site, and the greater of 30 or 10% of the area at a site of interest.
Although the inherent basis is binomial presence/absence, what kind of data are my n=30 or n=30+ samples?
What's the appropriate measure of central tendency - mean or median?
What's the appropriate metric for standard error?
And, to test difference between the reference site and site of interest, I'm thinking a 2x2 Chi-Square test with either average or median present/absent from the 30 and 30+ observations. Is this the best or appropriate test?